# cant load lib directory modules - uninitialized constant - rails 2 to rails 3 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, upgrade

I'm currently migrating an application in rails v2 to v3

In my `lib/` i've some modules in subdirectories, for example,
i've the `lib/search/host_search.rb`

with a

```
  module HostSearch
    def do_search(args)
       #...
    end
  end
```

then I need to use it in a controller named `Discovery::HostController < ApplicationController :`

```
def search_results
   output = HostSearch.do_search(:search_string => @search_string, 
     :page => params[:page],
     :user => @current_user)
   #...
end
```

But have I get:

```
uninitialized constant Discovery::HostController::HostSearch
```

..I tried to put this lines in application.rb but it doesn't work..

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that moving the module to the lib folder or explicitly including the folder to load worked, in your case 
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/search)

I think there's something syntaxical that we are missing. Another thing is that if you don't want to mess with the application.rb file, require the file, which if I remember, takes the file path from the lib folder eg: search/host_search <- check that.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put the `HostSearch` module under a search subdir, (ie in `lib/search/host_search.rb`), then you need to namespace it:

```
module Search
  module HostSearch
  end
end
```

If you don't want to namespace it, you can should move the file into the lib root: `lib/host_search.rb`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/514483