# Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use the following line in an initializer to autoload code in my `/lib` directory during development:

**config/initializers/custom.rb:**

```
RELOAD_LIBS = Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/**/*.rb'] if Rails.env.development?
```

(from [Rails 3 Quicktip: Auto reload lib folders in development mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407135313/http://www.hemju.com/2011/02/rails-3-quicktip-auto-reload-lib-folders-in-development-mode/))

It works great, but it's too inefficient to use in production- Instead of loading libs on each request, I just want to load them on start up. The same blog has [another article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130830141432/http://hemju.com:80/index.php/2010/09/rails-3-quicktip-autoload-lib-directory-including-all-subdirectories/) describing how to do this:

**config/application.rb:**

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

However, when I switch to that, even in development, I get NoMethodErrors when trying to use the lib functions.

Example of one of my lib files:

**lib/extensions.rb:**

```
Time.class_eval do
  def self.milli_stamp
    Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L').to_i
  end
end
```

Calling `Time.milli_stamp` will throw NoMethodError

I realize others have answered similar questions on SO but they all seem to deal with naming conventions and other issues that I didn't to have to worry about before- My lib classes already *worked* for per-request loading, I just want to change it to per-*startup* loading. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Is the config/initializers folder automatically loaded when a Rails app starts up?

Answer (score 550, accepted):

I think this may solve your problem:

1. in **config/application.rb**:

   ```
   config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
   ```

   and keep the right naming convention in **lib**.

   in **lib/foo.rb**:

   ```
   class Foo
   end
   ```

   in **lib/foo/bar.rb**:

   ```
   class Foo::Bar
   end
   ```
2. if you really wanna do some monkey patches in file like **lib/extensions.rb**, you may manually require it:

   in **config/initializers/require.rb**:

   ```
   require "#{Rails.root}/lib/extensions"
   ```

**P.S.**

- [Rails 3 Autoload Modules/Classes](https://bill.harding.blog/2011/02/23/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/) by Bill Harding.
- And to understand what does Rails exactly do about auto-loading?
  read [Rails autoloading — how it works, and when it doesn't](https://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/#fn1) by Simon Coffey.

Comment: @ifyouseewendy- You're exactly right- because **extensions.rb** wasn't following the Rails naming conventions, Rails wouldn't include it in the loading process. I got it working by manually requiring it.

Comment: @ifyouseewendy how can I include files before models are loaded? add the path to autoload it's cool, but how control the order of inclusion? thx

Comment: @Matrix "include files before models are loaded", you may manually require your file without using autoload feature.

Comment: @ifyouseewendy if I require it in initializer but the file are in autoload_path, it will be reloaded (loaded 2 times) or not? theire is a "require_once" like in php?

Comment: @Matrix nope, and why you manually require and add to autoload_path, what's the situation?

Comment: @ifyouseewendy I whant include all files in special folder in "app/", but, I don't want require it one by one, so I add the folder to the path, but certain files have to be include before models to works, so I have a problem^^

Comment: @Matrix Got it, I think you may add these certain files to `eager_load_paths`, which Rails will eager load on boot.

Comment: @ifyouseewendy the problem to this solution is it's loaded only at server start, if I want change data, I have to relaod server, I need a solution with no interuption of service... reloaded each time.

Comment: @Matrix Set `config.cache_classes = false` which is default in development env, which makes Rails reload classes and modules on each reqeust.

Comment: @ifyouseewendy If I have files under `lib/dir1/dir2/foo.rb` , your solution doesn't load them on start.. I am in 4.2

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Rails 5 API in production (but does in development).  I believe that you need to use `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`.  However, that has a major downside in that `eager_load_paths` loads everything in tasks as well.  I think that lulalala's solution is better.   Here's a blog post with more details: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/

Comment: I'm getting a `can't modify frozen Array` error when appending to `config.autoload_paths <<` in Rails 5.1. This question has the error and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7204837/34315. You need to use concatenation `config.autoload_paths +=`.

Answer (score 34):

Though this does not directly answer the question, but I think it is a good alternative to avoid the question altogether.

To avoid all the `autoload_paths` or `eager_load_paths` hassle, create a "lib" or a "misc" directory under "app" directory. Place codes as you would normally do in there, and Rails will load files just like how it will load (and reload) model files.

Comment: I am in Rails 4.2. and it doesn't auto load files under `app`, I need to do it manually......or need to put it in the autload path..

Comment: You are wrong, Arup, any subdirectories of app directory are automatically in the autoload_paths array in Rails 4.2.See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Excepting the `app/views` directory which does not get added; or rather gets explicitly removed.

Comment: Great answer.  Only thing that worked for me on rails 5/api.

Comment: Just remember that `lib` is meant for code that can be applied to multiple projects and might possibly be extracted to a gem. If not create a more appropriate folder under app search as `services/` or `presenters/` and even subdirs off these.

Comment: Will have to move dir under app folder to auto load in Rails 5. Just adding the [GitHub Discussion Link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142) for reference.

Answer (score 6):

This might help someone like me that finds this answer when searching for solutions to how Rails handles the class loading ... I found that I had to define a `module` whose name matched my filename appropriately, rather than just defining a class:

In file **lib/development_mail_interceptor.rb** (Yes, I'm using code from a Railscast :))

```
module DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
    def self.delivering_email(message)
      message.subject = "intercepted for: #{message.to} #{message.subject}"
      message.to = "myemail@mydomain.org"
    end
  end
end
```

works, but it doesn't load if I hadn't put the class inside a module.

Comment: In ruby "matching appropriately" means that the file is located in the file system at `LOAD_PATH/module/class.rb` (underscored) where `LOAD_PATH` is in the load paths used by the Ruby app (autoload_paths in the case of Rails).  `lib` has fluctuated from being auto loaded by Rails to not being autoloaded, and in recent versions (>= Rails 3.x) it is not autoloaded.  Whatever magic is making this work for you is not recommended.  Perhaps it is an old Railscast?

Answer (score 0):

Use config.to_prepare to load you monkey patches/extensions for every request in development mode.

```
config.to_prepare do |action_dispatcher|
 # More importantly, will run upon every request in development, but only once (during boot-up) in production and test.
 Rails.logger.info "\n--- Loading extensions for #{self.class} "
 Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/extensions/**/*.rb").sort.each do |entry|
   Rails.logger.info "Loading extension(s): #{entry}"
   require_dependency "#{entry}"
 end
 Rails.logger.info "--- Loaded extensions for #{self.class}\n"
```

end