# Use gem as library in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to use a gem as a library in Rails 4?

I have tried putting in a gem folder after cloning into lib folder but this doesn't seem to be working

Comment: One has to ask, why....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I know there is a way to Fork and use it from my forked repo by including in the Gemfile but I wanted to edit this along with the app itself so it just required more modifications. It just takes a lot of time for me to update, push, bundle update then restart the server every time when the gem is updated and when I need to test out the integration with the app itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set local path to gem in your `Gemfile` if I clearly understood the problem.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'my_perfect_gem', path: './path/to/my_perfect_gem'
```

I think it's better to set local gem location only in development and test environments, so wrap this line in a group. Unfortunately you should restart your rails server any time you've updated the gem.

May be there is a better approach such as using your gem as a part of application in lib folder – [Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4)

Comment: Usually changes to files in lib require a restart as well. In fact If I changed something in lib, I'd restart to make sure...