# How to create a module in lib folder in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a module in `/lib` folder & access that form my controllers. There are several solutions available in different websites, but modules are not loading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

to your `config/application.rb`

And then:

```
require 'file_name'
```

in your controller. That works for me (Rails 4).