# Creating a custom Devise Strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Been fighting with this for a while now, not sure why it isn't working.

The gist is looking to use Devise with LDAP.  I don't need to do anything except for authenticate so I have no need to use anything except for a custom strategy.

I created one based on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Authenticate-via-LDAP and as far as I can tell everything should work except whenever I try to run the server (or rake route) I get a `NameError`

```
lib/devise/models.rb:88:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Devise::Models::LdapAuthenticatable (NameError)
```

I've traced the error down to my `app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :timeoutable
end
```

If I remove `:ldap_authenticatable` then the crash goes away but I have no routes to `user#session` and a login prompt cannot be accessed.

My supporting files:

`lib/ldap_authenticatable.rb`

```
require 'net/ldap'
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable

      def authenticate!
        if params[:user]
          ldap = Net::LDAP.new
          ldap.host = 'redacted'
          ldap.port = 389
          ldap.auth login, password

          if ldap.bind
            user = User.where(login: login).first_or_create do |user|
            success!(user)
          else
            fail(:invalid_login)
          end
        end
      end

      def login
        params[:user][:login]
      end

      def password
        params[:user][:password]
      end

    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:ldap_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::LdapAuthenticatable)
```

And finally, inside `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> LDAP Configuration
  require 'ldap_authenticatable'
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :ldap_authenticatable
  end
end
```

I've exhausted my searches, maybe someone can see something I am missing.

Cheers

Comment: It's been a while, did you ever solve this?

Comment: This is the wiki guidance, but it does appear that custom strategies need more than this now.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `lib/ldap_authenticatable.rb` is in the autoload path or explicitly required? Since Rails 3 code in lib folder isn't autoloaded by default any more. Here is one way on how to [solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/1237265)

IMHO Devise is a great gem. However in order to write your own strategy you have to be familiar not only with Devise but with [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) source code as well, and a lot of boilerplate code needs to be written in various places, so I start to investigate how to make customizations easier for Devise and come up with this gem [devise_custom_authenticatable](https://github.com/AMekss/devise_custom_authenticatable). You can check it and probably it'll solve your problem in a different way. This gem is used in production code base for rather busy application, so it battle proven :)

Answer (score 2):

File paths should match namespaces.  You need to add 2 levels of directories.

```
mkdir lib/devise  
mkdir lib/devise/strategies  
mv lib/ldap_authenticatable.rb lib/devise/strategies/ldap_authenticatable.rb
```

Since you are namespaced to

```
module Devise  
  module Strategies  
    class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable  
...
```

Answer (score 2):

few steps to take care while creating custom strategy:

1. you will have to take care of the `strategies` folder as @csi mentioned along with it create a `models` folder and inside models create `ldap_authenticatable.rb` . so the structure will look like this.

   ```
   lib/devise/strategies/ldap_authenticatable.rb  
   lib/devise/models/ldap_authenticatable.rb
   ```
2. Add these lines to `lib/devise/models/ldap_authenticatable.rb`

   ```
   require Rails.root.join('lib/devise/strategies/ldap_authenticatable')  

   module Devise  
     module Models  
       module LdapAuthenticatable  
         extend ActiveSupport::Concern  

       end  
     end  
   end
   ```
3. In `config/initializers/devise.rb` add these lines to the top.

   ```
   Devise.add_module(:ldap_authenticatable, {   
     strategy: true,
     controller: :sessions,
     model: 'devise/models/ldap_authenticatable',
     route: :session
   })
   ```

This should take care of the custom auth.