# Where to place Grape custom validations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

I have a Rails 4 project which uses Grape for API stuff, I want to do some custom validations as described in the grape [documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape/#custom-validators). I want to know where should I place my custom validations code (like in lib file) and will I need to include or require something to use it inside my API file?

The documentation tells you to make a class but I am confused about the file structure if I have to write many custom validations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last time I used Grape I added custom validations to lib, I then required them into any API classes that used them. Eg:

**lib/api/validations/minimum_value.rb**

```
class AlphaNumeric < Grape::Validations::Validator
  def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
    unless params[attr_name] =~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/
      raise Grape::Exceptions::Validation, params: [@scope.full_name(attr_name)], message: "must consist of alpha-numeric characters"
    end
  end
end
```

**app/api/twitter.rb**

```
class Twitter::API < Grape::API
  require_relative '../../lib/api/validations/minimum_value'
```

Of course you may want to [add `lib/api/validations` to the auto-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4) to prevent having to manually require.

Comment: So for every custom validation I should have a new .rb file under the validations directory, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way to structure the code, from my experience.