# Rails 4: auto load from lib

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out the auto load thing, but I'm having a hard time making it to work without explicitly requiring the file.

Do I need to make some special configuration so that Rails 4 would be able to auto load files inside `lib` directory?

If I go to `rails console` and type `$LOAD_PATH` I'm able to see that `/home/some_user/workspace/rails/myapp/lib` is include into load path. This should mean that Rails will be able to auto load correct file?

So as I understand:
if I would place my files inside `lib/` directory and I would use the naming conventions, Rails should be able to automatically require the correct file if anywhere in my code I would do something like this:

`cats = Cats::SomeCat.new` (given that `lib/cats/some_cat.rb` exists)

and the `some_cat.rb` contains:

```
module Cats
    class SomeCat
        def initialize
            @name = "Some cat"
        end
   end
end
```

However, Rails will show me error `uninitialized constant CatController::Cats`.

If I add a line `require 'cats/some_cat'` everything will work. However, in 'The Rails 4 Way' I'm reading that :
 `The bottom line is that you should rarely need to explicitly load Ruby code in your Rails application (using require) if you follow the naming conventions`.

Am I using the wrong naming conventions or am I forced to use that
`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` thing?

Comment: Did you restart the application? It gets initialized only once when the application gets initialized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4)

Comment: As a side note: Subdirectores of `app/` ( and classes/modules therein) will be loaded, that's what I usually do - creating a subdir e.g. `app/workers`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` this  code  in

config/application.rb

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that you need the configuration in your `config/application.rb` directory.

As mentioned by Sobin, the best way would to include a `config.autoload_paths...` in that file.

You can find more about this in the rails guides

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html