# Can I force a namespace for Rails autoloading without nesting in a folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to tell Rails that all files in a certain folder are contained in a certain namespace?

Ie.

I have a file `bar.rb` in `app/foo`. Rails will assume this file defines `Bar`, but instead I want this file to define `Foo::Bar`.

I know I can achieve this by adding my root to Rails' autoload paths, but that isn't a real solution. Is there any other way I can tell Rails that all files within `app/foo` reside in the `Foo` namespace?

EDIT: File tree for clarification

```
app
  assets
  controllers
  models
  foo
    bar.rb
    quux.rb
```

I would like to be able to define `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::Quux` in respectively `bar.rb` and `quux.rb`, while also using Rails autoloading. Without having to resort to the tree structure as below:

```
app
  assets
  controllers
  models
  foo
    foo
      bar.rb
      quux.rb
```

Comment: Could you update your question with sort of "tree" of how your files are structured? It would be easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you would like to avoid putting your code in *app/lib/*, instead of directly into *app/*? If not, try point 1 from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/4381282) answer. This approach will make any new subdirectories loaded automatically. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'd really love an answer to this question as well. We have a similar situation, and nesting our modules in a directory makes our paths a little more convoluted.

Answer (score 3):

You can autoload files with namespaces corresponding to directories inside `/app` by adding `/app` to your autoload paths in your application config.

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app"
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is what the author of the question meant by

> I know I can achieve this by adding my root to Rails' autoload paths, but that isn't a real solution.

But this is definitely a real solution and the correct one. Doing this is fine and not at all unusual in my experience.

There are only minor side effects which are the cost of adopting the inconsistent naming conventions you want. If you refer to an undefined constant that matches the name of another directory in the app you'll get a slightly different error message.

```
# Models::Foo => LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Models::Foo, expected /app/models/foo.rb to define it)
```

But if you have existing namespaces that match directories in `app` loading will still work fine. Here's what Rails is doing:

It takes the paths added to `config.autoload_paths` and adds them to the defaults (the directories under `app`: `app/models`, `app/controllers`, `app/foo` etc). Then when a constant is referenced that is not already loaded Rails proceeds through those paths, looking for paths that match the constants. So when you reference `Foo::Bar` it looks for `app/models/foo/bar.rb`, `app/controllers/foo/bar.rb` etc. until it finds a file that defined `Foo::Bar`. All we're doing is adding `app/foo/bar.rb` to that lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't assume namespace, it assumes path to the source file depending on a namespace, so:

```
$ cat app/foo/bar.rb 
module Foo
  class Bar
    def bar
      puts "i'm here"
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
$ rails c
2.2.0 :007 > b=Foo::Bar.new
 => #<Foo::Bar:0x00000005272770> 
2.2.0 :008 > b.bar
i'm here
 => nil
```

Comment: Strange, when I do exactly the same, it gives me: `LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Bar, expected /home/(...)/app/foo/bar.rb to define it`

Comment: Strange is that rails fails to load looking at the proper path to the file... I'd double check that the (....) contains correct user name/project name... and maybe check file permissions too

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the folder you Rail's autoload paths configuration

```rb
# config/application.rb
# Rails 4
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("app", "foo")

# Rails 5+
 config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("app", "foo")
```