# Why are my scripts from lib/assets directory in a Rails application not executing, or erring out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use ConnectWise API's in my Rails 3 application. I've built and tested an API using plain ruby and it's successful. Now I'm trying to add this script into `lib/assets` in my Rails app to run but It seems to be either not executing the script, or executing and failing without giving me any error output.

Here are the successful Ruby scripts:

CompanyApis Class:

```
require 'builder'
class CompanyApis
  def self.get_company
    cw_company_id = 21920
    integrator_company_id = 'COMPANY_ID'
    integrator_login_id = 'INTERGRATOR_LOGIN'
    integrator_password = 'INTEGRATOR PW'

    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent=>2)
    xml.instruct!
    xml.tag!('soap:Envelope',
             :'xmlns:soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
             :xmlns => 'http://connectwise.com'){
      xml.tag!('soap:Body'){
        xml.tag!('GetCompany'){
          xml.tag!('credentials'){
            xml.CompanyId(integrator_company_id)
            xml.IntegratorLoginId(integrator_login_id)
            xml.IntegratorPassword(integrator_password)
          }
          xml.id(cw_company_id)
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

CwIntegrator Class:

```
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require './company_api'

class CwIntegrator
  cw_company_id = 21920
  cw_hostname = 'cw.host.com'
  companyapi_url = "https://#{cw_hostname}/v4_6_release/apis/2.0/CompanyApi.asmx"
  uri = URI.parse(companyapi_url)

  # Use for proxying to Kali
  #proxy_addr = '172.16.1.149'
  #proxy_port = 8080

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  request.add_field('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')
  request.add_field('SOAPAction', 'http://connectwise.com/GetCompany')
  request.body = CompanyApis.get_company
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  # Use for proxying to Kali
  #http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port, proxy_addr, proxy_port)

  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  response = http.start {|h| h.request(request)}
  company_info = []
  xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body).remove_namespaces!
  company_name = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/CompanyName').text
  company_street_addr = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/StreetLines/string')[0].text
  begin
    company_street_addr2 = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/StreetLines/string')[1].text
  end
  company_city = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/City').text
  company_state = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/State').text
  company_zip = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/Zip').text
  company_country = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/Country').text
  company_status = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/Status').text
  company_phone = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/PhoneNumber').text
  company_fax = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/FaxNumber').text
  company_www = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/WebSite').text

  company_info += [company_name: company_name, cw_company_id: cw_company_id, company_name: company_name,
                   company_street_addr: company_street_addr, company_street_addr2: company_street_addr2,
                   company_city: company_city, company_state: company_state, company_zip: company_zip,
                   company_country:company_country,company_status: company_status, company_phone: company_phone,
                   company_fax: company_fax, company_www: company_www]

  puts(company_info)
end
```

Running this script has this output:

ruby cw_integrator.rb 
`{:company_name=>"Orlando Fake Co, LLC.", :cw_company_id=>21920, :company_street_addr=>"STREET ADDR.", :company_street_addr2=>"Suite 400", :company_city=>"Orlando", :company_state=>"FL", :company_zip=>"32839", :company_country=>"United States", :company_status=>"Active Gold TTS", :company_phone=>"5558765309", :company_fax=>"", :company_www=>"www.myweb.com"}`

So to add this to the Rails app I've added two `.rb` files to `lib/assets`, `cw_apis.rb` and `cw_get_company_integrator.rb`. Here are their contents:

CwApis class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'builder'
class CwApis
  def self.get_company_xml_request
    cw_integrator_account = CwIntegratorAccount.first
    integrator_company_id = cw_integrator_account.integrator_company_id
    integrator_login_id = cw_integrator_account.integrator_login_id
    integrator_password = cw_integrator_account.integrator_password

    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent=>2)
    xml.instruct!
    xml.tag!('soap:Envelope',
             :'xmlns:soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
             :xmlns => 'http://connectwise.com'){
      xml.tag!('soap:Body'){
        xml.tag!('GetCompany'){
          xml.tag!('credentials'){
            xml.CompanyId(integrator_company_id)
            xml.IntegratorLoginId(integrator_login_id)
            xml.IntegratorPassword(integrator_password)
          }
          xml.id(cw_integrator_account.cw_company_id)
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

And CwGetCompanyIntegrator Class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'assets/cw_apis'

class CwGetCompanyIntegrator
  cw_integrator_account = CwIntegratorAccount.first
  cw_hostname = cw_integrator_account.cw_hostname
  company_api_url = "https://#{cw_hostname}/v4_6_release/apis/2.0/CompanyApi.asmx"
  uri = URI.parse(company_api_url)

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  request.add_field('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')
  request.add_field('SOAPAction', 'http://connectwise.com/GetCompany')
  request.body = CwApis.get_company_xml_request
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL
  response = http.start {|h| h.request(request)}
  xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body).remove_namespaces!

  company_name = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/CompanyName').text
  company_street_addr = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/StreetLines/string')[0].text
  begin
    company_street_addr2 = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/StreetLines/string')[1].text
  end
  company_city = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/City').text
  company_state = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/State').text
  company_zip = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/Zip').text
  company_country = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/DefaultAddress/Country').text
  company_status = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/Status').text
  company_phone = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/PhoneNumber').text
  company_fax = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/FaxNumber').text
  company_www = xml_doc.xpath('//Envelope/Body/GetCompanyResponse/GetCompanyResult/WebSite').text

  CompanyInfosController.create!(cw_company_id: cw_integrator_account.cw_company_id, company_name: company_name,
                                 company_street_addr: company_street_addr, company_street_addr2: company_street_addr2,
                                 company_city: company_city, company_state: company_state, company_zip: company_zip,
                                 company_country:company_country, company_status: company_status, company_phone: company_phone,
                                 company_fax: company_fax, company_www: company_www)
end
```

I'm trying to `execute` the `CwGetCompanyIntegrator` class in my `CwIntegratorAccountsController`.

Here is the code inside the `create` action from the `CwIntegratorAccountsController` I've omitted `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`:

```
require 'assets/cw_get_company_integrator'

class CwIntegratorAccountsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_company, :only => [:create,:new]

  # GET /cw_integrator_accounts
  # GET /cw_integrator_accounts.json

  def create
    unless CwIntegratorAccount.count >= 1
      @cw_integrator_account = CwIntegratorAccount.new(params[:cw_integrator_account])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @cw_integrator_account.save

          # Run the CW Integrator
          CwGetCompanyIntegrator
          format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'cw_integrator success' }
          #format.json { render json: @cw_integrator_account, status: :created, location: @cw_integrator_account }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @cw_integrator_account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I know that I'm getting past the `if @cw_integrator_account.save`, and `CwGetCompanyIntegrator` because I'm getting the redirect (and see it in the logs) from `format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'cw_integrator success' }`, but the `CwGetCompanyIntegrator` is not erring or executing (properly any way).

What is the proper way to make this class execute?

Comment: where is `@cw_integrator_account` assigned if `CwIntegratorAccount.count >= 1`

Comment: In the `new` method. I've omitted `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `lib` is not autoloaded by default. You need to add it to the autoload path - see [Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4)
2. In addition, `lib/assets` is used by the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). You should create a different folder for your classes.
3. Your code in `CwGetCompanyIntegrator` needs to be wrapped in a method, like the following block which you'd call using `CwGetCompanyIntegrator.call`

   ```
   class CwGetCompanyIntegrator
     def self.call
       # execute code here
     end
   end
   ```