# How to create an interface on a per object type level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, delegation

In my rails (4.2.1) app, I have a Type (model) that contains records with :name of "string", "integer", etc.

I want the user to be able to pass in values and check if it is a valid object of a given type. So, the pseudocode is:

```
check_value(:integer, "1") #=> true
check_value(:integer, "foo") #=>false
```

I would like to add new types over time which have their own logic to check_value for that type.

Here are a few alternatives I have looked at:

## 1 Add one method per type directly to Type model -

```
# app/models/type.rb
# inside class Type...
def check_string_value(val)
 true
end

def integer_value(val)
 begin
  Integer(val)
 rescue
  return false
 end
 return true    
end
```

This would work, but would require me to modify the type.rb file each time a new field type is added, which I would like to avoid.

## 2 per object methods in a file per type:

```
# lib/types/integer_type/integer_type.rb
int = Type.where(name: "integer").first
class << int
  def check_value(val)
    begin
     Integer(val)
    rescue
     return false
    end
    return true   
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that I cannot call that particular instance of the integer type to pass in the verification call, since I do not construct it in my calling code.

So, neither of these seems ideal - I would like a technique that delegates the verify call from type.rb to the individual type to handle. Is this possible? How could I do it?

Comment: It seems like you'll need at least some code somewhere for every type, which prompts me to ask: What's the use of the database table?

Comment: @Jordan Because I expect to add types later as plugins, and they 'just work' without having to modify the core code.

Comment: But *how* will they "just work"? You'll need to add code *somewhere*, so what do you gain by having each type tied to a database record?

Comment: I could have a method in the Type class called verify_value(type_name, value) which could delegate to that type without bothering about what the per type behavior is.

Comment: Right. So your Type class will know where the code for each type lives. What do you gain by having each type tied to a database record?

Comment: So I can find available types in my system

Comment: But the Type class already knows what types are available. Or anyway it should, and can easily, be implemented that way.

Comment: And the Type model doesn't need to know where he class lives. Rails convention will load code in the library folder, for example

Comment: OK, forget about the database. How can I implement this in the rails App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this in Ruby. Here's one extremely basic way. Have each type module define a `check` method and then "register" itself with the Type module with e.g. `Type.register(:integer, IntegerType)`. Then `Type.check(type, value)` need only check the registered types and, if one matches, delegate to its `check` method:

#### type.rb

```
module Type
  @@checkers = {}

  def self.check(type, value)
    if @@checkers.key?(type)
      @@checkers[type].check(value)
    else
      raise "No registered type checker for type `#{type}'"
    end
  end

  def self.register(type, mod)
    @@checkers[type] = mod
  end

  def self.registered_types
    @@checkers.keys
  end

  def self.load_types!
    Dir['./types/*.rb'].each do |file|
      require file
    end
  end
end

Type.load_types!
```

#### types/integer.rb

```
module Type
  module Integer
    def self.check(value)
      !!Integer(value)
    rescue ArgumentError
      false
    end
  end
end

Type.register(:integer, Type::Integer)
```

#### types/string.rb

```
module Type
  module String
    def self.check(value)
      true
    end
  end
end

Type.register(:string, Type::String)
```

#### And then...

```
p Type.registered_types # => [ :integer, :string ]
p Type.check(:integer, "1") # => true
p Type.check(:integer, "a") # => false
p Type.check(:string, "a") # => true
```

Of course, you could go much fancier than this with metaprogramming (see the previous revision of this answer for a solution that used `Module#extend` instead of keeping registered modules in a simple hash) or, say, lazy loading, but you get the idea. The "core" type module doesn't have to know the names of the other modules (and you could define `load_types!` however you want, or do that somewhere else entirely). The only requirement is that the modules respond to `"check_#{type}"`.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan - this is a good ruby answer. Would this work if I just plopped the 'types' folder with type.rb, string.rb, etc. from your example under lib? I can get by without the type defined in the database. My thought was to enable people registering types in the future through an interface and a plugin framework, but I can extend it when I get there.

Comment: It should work with minimal modification. You may have to fiddle with the paths in e.g. `load_types!` a bit. As always you should write some tests to cover the expected functionality. As for making a plugin framework, there's lots of prior art out there, so it's definitely worth looking at what has come before to avoid repeating their mistakes.

Comment: P.S. I edited my answer to simplify it a bit. Now it uses a simple hash to keep registered type checkers, instead of having each `extend` the base module. This also makes it easier to get a list of the registered types (and add other features, e.g. each could respond to `description` to get a human-friendly name or help text).

Comment: Thanks, I agree with the need to modify the paths in load_types! - will also look at plugin models later. Accepting answer now. This other thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/456735 has some information about how to reload lib files on a per request versus at server start time - could be handy to coerce this approach into rails.