# Rails 4.1.1: uninitialized constant during initial Rails configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to add a microapp for errors to be processed (file I placed inside the lib folder).

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
    config.exceptions_app = FooApp.new(Rails.public_path)
  end
end
```

But Rails raises an unitialized constant (NameError) during it's initialization. Recently I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4) post and tried every solution from there, but got no result. What actually I've tried:

1. Name a class and a filename according to convention (even tried to simplify to a single word - class Foo, filename lib/foo.rb).
2. Use `config.eager_load_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )` rather than `config.autoload_paths`, same effect. :(
3. Create an initializer file and load a class with require: `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/foo"`
   It doesn't work - seems initializers are performed after the initial Rails configuration.
4. Move the file into app/misc but it doesn't help.
5. Put a class inside a module with the same name, rename a class while it's still in the module - no effect.

The only working solution I found - is to require a file right inside the Rails configuration block, but... it's a freaky solution. Probably there still exists an idiomatic one?

Comment: Why don't you just use [`exception_handler`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler), which does exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Rich Peck, because I don't need custom error pages.