# Set a breakpoint in lib/ directory of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I've put the code which processes document generation to `lib/parser` folder in my Rails application. But now I can't debug that code: neither `binding.pry` nor `byebug` have an effect. Raising exceptions also doesn't show up neither in logs nor in `rails server`'s `stdout` channel. Is there any way to fine-tune it, or to debug it I have to put it somewhere else?

The module itself is included in controller with

```
require Rails.root.join("lib/parser/parser.rb")
```

Comment: That requires the file, it doesn't include any methods in the controller.

Comment: @j-dexx but why does that work then?

Comment: Why does what work then?

Comment: @j-dexx all of the logic in `lib/parser`. How does not including the methods in the controller correlate with breakpoints not being triggered?

Comment: What you have done is say I want to use this file.  You've not at any point said include these methods in the controller based on the code you provided.  If you can post the full code then we'll be able to help you more.  You'll need to do something like `include Parser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Naremy, I've found my mistake. The problem was following: I've had `begin...rescue` block which was catching errors stopping them from floating up to output of `rails server`. And as the error was the same as in the other chunk of code (where I was trying to set breakpoint), I couldn't find it.
So removing `rescue` made a move, and now everything works as expected.

So the overall fact is: if you catch a error, neither `rails server` output nor `better_errors` gem will show you anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can relaunch your server after each change and it will work but if you have a lot of code it can be long.

You can also add your code in the autoload_paths (into application.rb) :

`config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib',  '**/')]`

See also [Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4)

Comment: I understand that, but the question is that I can't use debuggers in that code, which would help me a lot to understand what's going wrong

Comment: You mean if you write a binding.pry in your main home controller action, it does not have effect? If it's the case it's not related to the lib folder but related to your use of binding.pry. In the other case, it's probably due to the fact that the code in not reloaded. It expect that it's a reloading concern cause you write that raising exception does not have effect.

Comment: no, I put `binding.pry` in one of functions in `lib/parser/parser.rb`. It works if it's in controller, but not there.

Comment: Ok, so no output, raise nor binding event after a restart. I know that not the answer you want but your code is probably not called. Start by ensure that your code is loaded, just make a raise in your main function or initializer class, launch a raise console and see if it crash.

Comment: but the logic itself works, so it's called properly. Can't post the code right now.

Comment: hmm, you were right. The problem was that I was catching the error, thus it didn't show in `rails server` output. Thank you! And sorry for stupid questions )