# how to call rake tasks from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

i have this task in `/lib/tasks/scriping.rake`

```
namespace :scriping do
    task :list => :environment do
        client = CloudscrapeClient.new
        Robot.all.each do |robot|
            execution_id = client.runs(robot.list_run_id).execute(connect: true)
        end
    end
```

i have tried this code in controller. But it's not working.

```
Tasks::scriping.execute
```

When is run this command in console it works!

```
bundle exec rake scriping:list
```

how can i call **task :list** this task from controller

Answer (score 4):

Best solution is to move that shared code to a class!

```
# app/services/cloud_scrape_client_runner.rb
class CloudScrapeClientRunner
  def self.perform
    client = CloudscrapeClient.new

    Robot.all.each do |robot|
      execution_id = client.runs(robot.list_run_id).execute(connect: true)
    end
  end
end
```

Then make sure you're loading that folder

```
# in config/application.rb:

config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('services')
```

Then in your rake task:

```
namespace :scriping do
  task :list => :environment do
    CloudScrapeClientRunner.perform
  end
end
```

and in your controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def index
    CloudScrapeClientRunner.perform
  end

end
```

WHY!?!

Because I am guessing that `CloudScrapeClientSomething` is sloooow and you want to do it asynchronously.

**what you want:** click link, have it trigger the controller to start the task.

**what you don't want:** click the link, have the entire app freeze until the task is completed.

Comment: Thanks you but it's get error to me. uninitialized constant AdminController::CloudScrapeClientRunner

Comment: You should add an extra folder called `libs` for this stuff. and add it to the autoload path http://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/1536309