# require bindata in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bindata

I have a set of files that are in the lib directory of a Ruby on Rails application.

I have a model that needs to use these files.  In my model I have the following:

```
require_relative '../../some_path_to_file_without_extention'
```

(Side note; I would love to know a way to require all the files, instead of require_relative for each file).

The file that I require_relative has the following require in it.

```
require "bindata"
```

When I try to access functions from the require_relative file I get the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bindata
```

This is happening for other gems that are being required in the set of files as well.  I just chose `bindata` as an example.

I have `bindata` in my Gemfile.  When I run `bundle show bindata` it shows me the path to `bindata`.

I even put `require 'bindata'` in my model, but it gave me the same load error.

How do I stop the `LoadError`?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

## Update 1

When I run `bundle show` . I get the following:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  ...
  * bcrypt (3.1.11)
  * bindata (2.3.4)
  ...
```

Then in the console, requiring bcrypt works but bindata does not.

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'bcrypt'
=> true
```

But bindata does not.

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'bindata'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bindata
```

## Update 2

Ok so I know is has to be something with how I am loading my rails environment.

```
bundle exec irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'bindata'
=> true
```

## Update 3

So I went back a few git commits and keep trying to add the gems and see if they would load in my rails console.  I went back far enough were it did.  Did not know what was different.  However, I also noticed when my spring server was restarted then my gems would load in my rails console.

Answer (score 0):

To require all the files in the lib folder, add `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` to your `application.rb`, this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650564/3739191

Now,

```
require 'bindata'
```

should work :)

Comment: I am pretty sure it should work, but for some reason (probably something I am still doing wrong) it did not work for me.  I added more info to my the question.