# Test Ruby module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm very new to Ruby and and RSpec. I would like to create basic Spec file for this module:

```
module DownloadAttemptsHelper

  def download_attempt_filter_select_options
    search_types = [
      [I18n.t("helpers.download_attempts.search_types_default"),          'default'          ],
      [I18n.t("helpers.download_attempts.search_types_account_id"),      'account_id'      ],
      [I18n.t("helpers.download_attempts.search_types_remote_ip"),        'remote_ip'        ],
    ]
    options_for_select(search_types)
  end
end
```

Small test

```
describe DownloadAttemptsHelper do
  it "does something" do
    expect(1).to be_odd
  end
end
```

I get:

```
`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant DownloadAttemptsHelper (NameError)
```

Do I need to import the directory path and module name?
Can you give me some very basic example how I can test this module?

Comment: There is a lot of tutorials and guides in the internet, how to write specs, have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, but I'm too new to this language. Can you give me some basic example, please?

Comment: It's not a language it's a test framework. Here is the first link from the google. https://www.codeschool.com/courses/testing-with-rspec

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, you need to make sure your module is being loaded when the server starts. Open up a `rails c` and check if you can access your module there. If not, you can do something like described here [Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4)

That is, make Rails autoload classes in the `lib` directory, if that's where your helper is located in.

Answer (score -1):

You have to include the module in the rspec test file to make it's methods available in the test cases:

```
describe "DownloadAttemptsHelper" do
  include DownloadAttemptsHelper

  it "does something" do
    expect(1).to be_odd
  end
end
```

Comment: I get again the same error: ``<top (required)>': uninitialized constant DownloadAttemptsHelper (NameError)`. Probably I need to specify directory and file location?