# How to require modules in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rails app with a module called `http_helpers` that lives in `app/lib/modules/` and I want to use the methods in the module in my controllers. I was thinking of requiring the module in `application_controller.rb` so that the module's methods will be accessible to every controller.

#### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  require "http_helpers"
end
```

However I'm getting an error:

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- http_helpers):
```

I'm new to dealing with this side of rails (or ruby for that matter) and would very much appreciate some suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You use [Module#`include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-include)/`extend` modules, not files in Rails, because every file (at least those under `app` directory are preloaded).

So

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include HttpHelpers
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

## edit

Unless you're on Rails 5+, you need to [add the folder to the autoload paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4):

```
#config/application.rb:
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'lib', 'modules')
```

Comment: That's because Rails pre-loads everything

Comment: Okay but now I'm getting this error: `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::HttpHelpers):`

Comment: @Mark maybe because you do not have a file called `http_helpers` with module called `HttpHelpers`? ;) Naming is crucial in Rails, because it is a base for lot's of magic behind it

Comment: my module is: `module HttpHelpers` and the filename is: `http_helpers.rb`

Comment: @Mark is it under `app/helpers` directory? Also, if you name it `ApplicationHelper` you won't even need to `include` it, because Rails is smart enough to include modules from `helpers` directory into the corresponding (by name) controllers

Comment: No, I mentioned in my post that the module is in `app/lib/modules/` and I'd like to keep it there if possible

Comment: You need to add the lib dir to the preload paths

Comment: @RichardPeck the `lib` dir is under `app`, so I doubt it is the case

Comment: @RichardPeck or is it only Rails 5 preloads everything from under `app`?..

Comment: I believe it's only Rails 5 which preloads all the /app folder

Comment: I fixed it by removing the modules directory and simply putting the module in `app/lib`, but why can't rails seem to locate the module if its another layer deep?

Comment: @Mark to be honest I can't tell... Anyway, if the answer satisfies you - make sure to accept it, unless you're waiting for more to come.

Comment: I think it might be a recursion issue

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 5+ (you have not specified), you can now include helpers directly in the controller using the [`helpers` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24866):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    helpers.your_http_method
  end
end
```

If your module has specific helpers, you should convert it into an engine and then put the helpers into the `app/helpers` folder of your engine. We do this with a framework we use in our production apps:

[image]

This will allow you to call the helpers in your controllers without polluting your app's structure.

--

The trick is to make the engine a gem and put it in `vendor/gems` - this way you can reference it in the `Gemfile` as follows:

```
#Gemfile
gem "your_engine", path: "vendor/gems/your_gem"
```

---

If you decide to extract the functionality into an engine (you should), the setup would be as follows:

```
# app/vendor/gems/your_engine/lib/engine.rb
module YourEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace YourEngine
  end
end

# app/vendor/gems/your_engine/app/helpers/your_engine/http_helpers.rb
class YourEngine::HTTPHelpers
  ....
end
```