# twilio capability token generate for voice call integration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

error: "uninitialized constant TwilioCapability"

Twilio capability token generate issue on live site and staging this is working properly.

This is my code of generate Twilio Capability token

```
class Twilio::TokenController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def generate
    token = ::TwilioCapability.generate("#{params[:appointment_id]}#{params[:from_type]}")
    render json: { token: token }
  end
end

twilocapabilty.rb file code

class TwilioCapability
  def self.generate(id)
    account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token  = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    capability = Twilio::Util::Capability.new account_sid, auth_token

    application_sid = ENV['TWIML_APPLICATION_SID']
    capability.allow_client_outgoing application_sid
    capability.allow_client_incoming id

    capability.generate
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe there might be a couple of issues with this, mainly answered in [this existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4).

Firstly, make sure that, if your class is called `TwilioCapability` then the file name matches it via the Rails naming rules. It should be called `twilio_capability.rb`.

Other than that, I guess you are keeping the file in the `lib` directory (so it should be `lib/twilio_capability.rb`). If you are not already autoloading files from `lib` in production, then you should add the following to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Fantastic! Could you mark this answer as correct so that others can see that it helped too? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sure, Thanks -